# Can't remove VladimirPopov_WebForms from my server

Tags: magento-1.9

Trying to remove VladimirPopov_WebForms from FTP.

1. Went to /app/etc/modules/VladimirPopov_WebForms.xml and put status to false.
2. Admin panel -> System - Configuration-< VladimirPopov_WebForms disabled
3. Removed all files from server
4. cleared cash
5. compilation is off

now, main page of admin panel is working but if I go to for example to Cache page Im getting this:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Webforms_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php:547 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php(325): Mage::helper('webforms') #1 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->_isEnabledModuleOutput(Object(Varien_Simplexml_Element)) #2 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php(98): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->_buildMenuArray() #3 /public_html/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Block/Adminhtml/Magento/Menu.php(23): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->getMenuArray() #4 /public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/menu.phtml(30): Ess_M2ePro_Block_Adminhtml_Magento_Menu->getMenuArray() #5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dscfilte/...') #6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Update: after returning everything back, I noticed that there is one table mag1_webforms and without this table nothing works, really confused now, dont know what I did wrong.

Comment: compilation is enable in your webshop?

Comment: everything was off, I end up deleting everything except one table from database and /app/etc/modules/VladimirPopov_WebForms.xml, for now it's working. Maybe somebody here gonna have an idea

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this and was looking for some help myself.  I followed these steps:

-log in to ssh and go to /app/etc/modules and edit VladimirPopov_WebForms.xml and set true to false
-Look for tables in the sql database that are directly for this module
webforms
webforms_fields
webforms_fieldsets
webforms_logic
webforms_message
webforms_quickresp
webforms_results
webforms_results_values
webforms_store
-Check the tables to see if they have any valuable data and download it
delete these tables
-In Database, Remove resource config record for the respective module from core_resource - use search function to find %webforms%
-Remove the app/code/community/VladimirPopov folder

BEWARE, followed these steps and it broke the site. (Note, i did forget to clear the cache and that may have been the problem but when i did the extra step below it started working without clearing the cache)

So I used phpmyadmin to do a search on the database and delete references to webforms and i was able to get it back working. I am not sure exactly which ones corrected the issue but I am able to use the site  normally and don't have any of the webforms tables left over.